# How do i make the recursion break when n=1 without using exit(1) inside the if block?

Tags: c, algorithm

this is the program to find the prime factors of any number.
PS:you may criticize me for the algorithm I used but it came out when I was too rigid to use the orthodox one. 
How do I make the recursion break when n=1 without using `exit(1)` inside  the if block?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void prime(int);

int main(){
    int n;

    scanf("%d",&n);         
    prime(n);

    return 0;
}

int i=2;

void prime(int n){
    int n1=n;

    {
        float i1=i;
        if(n==1)
            return;

        int c1=n/i;
        float c2=n/i1;
        if(c1==c2)
        {
            printf("%d ",i);
            n=n/i;
            if(n!=1)
                printf("x ");

            prime(n);
        }
        else{
            i++;
            prime(n);
        }
    }
    if(n!=1)
        printf("%d",n);
    printf("\n");
}
```

but i am getting some unwanted  output as

```
15
3 x 5 
5
5
5
15
```

If I use `exit(1)` instead of return in the if block, I am not getting anything extra but what if I don't want to use `exit(1)`?
why is the value of `n` in the recursive function is turning to 5 after it have already turned to 1?

Comment: Time for you use a debugger.

Comment: Recommendation: When asking questions, remove the user input. Instead call the function under test with a value that you know will trigger the behaviour you wish to investigate.

Comment: not interested in debugging this as i have already debugged it but what confuses me is how after n  becomes 1 it again turns to 5 in this case

Comment: The function breaks recursion with return just as it is.

Comment: Well, n doesn't turn to 5 back, each time you call a function independent stack is created, I mean that each time you call a function it has a independent COPY of the variable value, independent of all the other calls. You see 5 from the recursive calls that had n equal to 5, you see 15 from the first call to the function (ie. the one that called `prime(15)` from `main()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(n!=1)
        printf("%d",n);
    printf("\n");
```

get rid of these lines.